# Can unplugging a VM be harmful?

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-machine, operating-systems, shutdown, power

We know that unplugging the power cable from a PC may damage your hard drive and may corrupt your OS.

Could the same harm (or any harm) happen if I unplug a VM (simulated by Power Off option in VBox for example)? Could it possibly harm my virtual image?

This would be assuming I don't want to save any data prior to shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

*Damage your hard drive* is a bad choice of words because it can imply physical damage, and you won't physically damage anything by unplugging your system.

Similarly *harm my virtual image* is also a bad choice of words because it can imply the files defining the VM will be damaged for some reason and then things like the VBox being unable to recogize the VM will happen.  Unless the VM software is badly designed/configured nothing you do in the VM can affect the VM definition files, etc. itself.

Modern operating systems do not write data to disk right away, they buffer writes and schedule them for performance.  What a sudden halt of the operating system can do (and this includes crashes as well as loss of power) is to prevent these writes from ever getting to the disk.

Modern filesystems are *journaled*, meaning that the OS writes a list of what it intends to do to an area of the disk before actually performing that list.  So if it gets interrupted it can backtrack through that list and make things consistent - not to recover any data, but to make the filesystem itself not be corrupted.

Non-journaled filesystems (FAT*, ext2) don't have that protection and can require `chkdsk`, `fsck` - which might fail in severe cases leading to an unmountable volume and loss of data.

If they are corrupted and unrecoverable, you can format the volume and install a new OS.  Same with a VM.  So there is no difference.

Comment: Even journaled filesystems aren't fool-proof. Especially if you force shutdown them while in the middle of write actions corruption may still occur. I've seen it happen too many times on NTFS, HFS+, Ext4, BtrFS and even on ZFS. No filesystem is 100% safe from corruption. Journaling is no substitute for proper backup.

Comment: @LawerenceC So as a conclusion: Can we say, NO unplugging a VM will NOT harm anything? Taking into account: 1- Current OS don't write data directly and 2- Journaled file systems

Comment: The files/filesystem *in* the VM could be corrupted, just as they would on a physical system.  The VM itself will be OK, you would just have to reinstall the operating system in it or recover the files from backup.

Comment: @LawrenceC, from my little experience dealing with VMs, I note that even if one chooses "Power Off", the VBox takes sometime to switch the VM off. Especially if you have a windows VM. Which may mean that "Power Off" option can never be harmful (even to file systems). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AhmedWas We cannot know that based on the information in the question. It could be an ACPI please-power-off event (which the OS can handle gracefully by initiating an OS shutdown), or a hard shutdown (similar to if you hold the power button on your ATX system depressed for a few seconds).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, yes, it could harm your Windows installation on your VM. It's possible that it would be fine by using that method, but just because it works doesn't mean it's a good idea.

If your VM is locked up, sometimes you have no other choice, but it's better practice to just 'pause' your VM when you are done using it for the time, or do a proper shutdown. Sometimes Windows Updates have installed partially and wait until proper shutdown to finish configuring them, and if you force power off the system it can cause issues.